# C++ passing class to constructor = not passing same instance?

Tags: c++, arduino

It seems that, when I pass an class it is not passing a persistant (the same) instance of that class as I would expect.  I'm assuming this has something to do with memory state but I would appreciate it if someone could explain exactly what is happening.  The issue is easily demonstrated as follows :

#### Main.ino

```
#include "Debug.h"
#include "Box.h"

Debug debug;
Box box(debug);

void loop(){
  debug.message("loop");
  debug.line();
}

void setup(){
  debug.init();
  box.init();
  debug.message("Setup Complete");
  debug.line();
}
```

#### Debug.h

```
#ifndef DEBUG_H
#define DEBUG_H

class Debug {
  private:
    bool state;
  public:
    Debug();
    void init();
    void message(const char *str);
    void message(int);
    void line();
};

#endif
```

#### Debug.cpp

```
#include "Debug.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

Debug::Debug() : state(false) {}

void Debug::init() {
  if (state == false){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    state = true;
  }
}
void Debug::message(const char *messageChar) {
  if (state){
    const char *p;
    p = messageChar;
    while (*p) {
        Serial.print(*p);
        p++;
    }
  }
}
void Debug::message(int messageInt) {
  if (state){
    Serial.print(messageInt);
  }
}
void Debug::line() {
  if (state){
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

#### Box.h

```
#ifndef BOX_H
#define BOX_H

#include "Debug.h"

class Box {  
  private:
    Debug debug;
  public:
    Box(Debug &debug);
    void init();
};

#endif
```

#### Box.cpp

```
#include "Box.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

Box::Box(Debug &debug):
  debug(debug)
{}

void Box::init(){
  // Switches
  pinMode(28, INPUT_PULLUP);

  debug.message("Box intialized");
  debug.line();
}
```

So the above code outputs to serial:

```
Setup Complete
```

If I modify Box::init() to

```
void Box::init(){
  // Switches
  pinMode(28, INPUT_PULLUP);

  debug.init();
  debug.message("Box intialized");
  debug.line();
}
```

I get what I want :

```
Box initialized
Setup Complete
```

If I get rid of Box constructor class and instead do

```
void Box::init(Debug &debug){
  this->debug = debug;
  
  // Switches
  pinMode(28, INPUT_PULLUP);

  debug.message("Box intialized");
  debug.line();
}
```

Called via Main.ino like

```
void setup(){
  debug.init();
  box.init(debug);
  debug.message("Setup Complete");
  debug.line();
}
```

I get the desired response again.  I don't understand why my first attempt doesn't work nor do I feel comfortable knowing what best practices are.  I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: FYI, differentiating between types and variable name by one case letter (`Debug` vs. `debug`) is poor coding style and can lead to typo issues.  The C++ standard says that the first 32 letters must be unique, so that gives you a lot of choices in variable naming.

Comment: Also, you may want to change your coding style so that member variable names have different names than parameters.  This kind of style eliminates the need for the `this->` syntax.  Examples:  prefixing member names with "m_", or adding a "_" as a suffix.

Comment: The `debug` member variable in `Box` is a value, not a reference or pointer. So it will always be a copy in both of your code samples

Comment: @ThomasMatthews _"The C++ standard says that the first 32 letters must be unique"_ -- _**what**_. I have never seen this in [\[lex.name\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name). Do you have a source for this? If this were the case, then how are things like `std::less` and `std::less_equal` valid? They share the same prefix

Comment: @Human-Compiler, the semi-quote is from MISRA C++ standard.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews MISRA is for embedded development AFAIK, and is also replaced by AUTOSAR (at least for automotive). Secondly, MISRA only defines `2–10–4` -- which requires uniqueness, but not 32 characters of it -- unless I'm missing something. Third... MISRA isn't C++ standard -- those two things are *very different*. One is the entirety of the language spec -- the other is (often subjective) suggestions on coding practices that can be overridden by a detailed compliance matrix/procedure.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews an aside, my current team has decided to outlaw member variable prefixes (or suffixes, any type of designator) in favor of using `this->` instead. It's rage inducing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : Thanks for the advice.  I will start doing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `Debug` values in your code. One global, one member of the `Box` class.

Those are two distinct values, since `Box` create or copy from a value to create its own, and there's the global one.

A solution would be to contain a reference or a pointer.

Here's the example with a reference:

```
class Box {  
  private:
    Debug& debug;
    //   ^---- there
  public:
    Box(Debug &debug);
    void init();
};
```

If you want `Box` to still be assignable, then use a pointer:

```
class Box {  
  private:
    Debug* debug;
    //   ^---- now it's a star
  public:
    Box(Debug &debug);
    void init();
};

Box::Box(Debug &debug):
  debug(&debug)
{} //   ^----- here, we take the address of the debug variable.
```

Since references are immutable, you loose some important feature of the language: assignment.

```
struct thing {
    int& ref;
};

int main () {
    int a, b;
    thing t1{a}, t2{b};

    t1 = t2; // ERROR!
}
```

The assignment would cause `t1.ref` to point to `b` after the assignment.

Pointer has a more difficult syntax and hard to guess semantics. However, they play very well with assignment since they give you more freedom:

```
struct thing {
    int* ptr;
};

int main () {
    int a, b;
    thing t1{&a}, t2{&b};

    t1 = t2; // Works, t1.ptr points to b
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your solution worked for me.  I'm not clear what you mean by having "Box be assignable" or to put another way...I'm not clear why I would use a pointer vs a reference.  Would you be willing to expand on this point?

Comment: You could add a method called SetDebug(Debug &newDebug) that would change debug pointer to the &newDebug (from the ctor's Debug object).  For example, you may have a memory based Debug object and stdout-based Debug object (derived object?) that you want to swap out at runtime.

Comment: @hendr1x I added a part at the end that highlight the difference. Depending on the use case, I end up taking one or the other depending on my needs.